# Mass unzipping of files containing signs to be escaped and renaming of created folders using regexp

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I need to create a simple bash one line sript that will do as follow:

1. Find all zip files in folder
2. Unzip each file
3. Rename result folders.

The first part is quite easy:

```
find . -type f -name '*.zip'
```

The problem comes next, as the files looks this way:

```
ab_firstname_somestring_A!1.zip
ab_secondname_somestring_A!1.zip
ab_thirddname_somestring_A1.zip
```

etc. The problem comes when using xargs - when it doesn't receive escaped filenames it will not extract them.
The last problematic step is renaming - the result folders will have exact same name as original zip file without .zip at the end, and I would like to rename then during the process so only this part remains:

```
firstname
secondname
thirdname
```

The only thing that is known - the name will be between first _ and second _.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the synax that is actually problematic? Generally, you should be using `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` if you are using `xargs`, or just `-exec`, but not very clear from the question what the actual issue is.

Comment: I did: `find . -type f -name '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 tar -xzf
` and it returns me with: `tar: ./ab_firstname_somestring_A!1.zip: Not found in archive` kind of error

Comment: Try adding an `-l` to the `xargs`. I think `tar` can only take one argument to unzip.

Comment: `illegal option -- l` - seems like tar on mac doesn't know this option

Comment: Looks like it should be `xargs -0 -L 1 -x` on `BSD xargs`, or just use `find ... -exec tar -xzf {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comments above. I think you are looking for something like

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec bash -c \
  ' tar -xzf "$1" && f=$1 && f=${f#*_} && mv -iv -- "${1%%.zip}" "${f%%_*}" ' \
bash {} \;
```

If you want to do something else with other `zip` archives, you can do something like this instead

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec bash -c ' \
    if [[ $1 =~ _(.*)_(.*)_ ]]; then \
        tar -xzf "$1" && mv -iv -- "${1%%.zip}" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; \
    else \
        : #Do something else with other zip archives, that don't have 3 underscores
    fi ' \
bash {} \;
```

e.g.

```sh
> tree
.
├── ab_firstname_somestring_A!1.zip
├── ab_secondname_somestring_A!1.zip
└── ab_thirddname_somestring_A1.zip

0 directories, 3 files
>    find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec bash -c \
>       ' tar -xzf "$1" && f=$1 && f=${f#*_} && mv -iv -- "${1%%.zip}" "${f%%_*}" ' \
>     bash {} \;
‘./ab_firstname_somestring_A!1’ -> ‘firstname’
‘./ab_secondname_somestring_A!1’ -> ‘secondname’
‘./ab_thirddname_somestring_A1’ -> ‘thirddname’
```

Comment: It all seems quite fine, just one thong - some folders doesn't go with the rule that same zip filename will produce same folder. Only `ab_firstname_somethingelse!A` works always (final folder name is between first _ and second _. Is there a way to do it without going through second find loop?

Comment: @MarcinBobowski If you mean that not all zip archives will have 3 underscores, with the name between the first and second, see edit.

Comment: Original zip files all are the same, just after unzipping some unzipped folders doesn't go with same naming, but the desired name is always between first and second underscore. I was able to do it in two loops: `find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec bash -c \ ' tar -xzf "$1" ' bash {} \;
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c \ ' f=$1 && f=${f#*_} && mv -iv -- "${1%%.zip}" "${f%%_*}"  '  bash {} \;` and it did well, but perhaps there is a better / easierr way?

Comment: @MarcinBobowski Could you provide an example with zip archive names? Not really sure what you mean.